After minimazing a window it keeps at the desktop in starnge condition
I cant really explain it, so here's is a video demonstaration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbeyLd7D81Q
It's actually just randomly happens, expecially when im using multiple desktops (not physical monitors).
Only one fix I found by myself is to log out or reboot. But it's really annoying to do that. I tried googling a lot but i didnt find anything useful. Can someone help?
Details:

OS: elementary OS 8
Laptop: Acer Aspire 3

(just my thought) I think there's a way to fix that by restarting the desktop (patheon, is i remeber right), but I dont't know ho to do that
